# Data doesn't update when pressing enter on the search

Tags: next.js, netlify

I'm using the [Open Weather API](https://openweathermap.org/api) to learn some [NextJS](https://nextjs.org).

On my [staging site](https://bn-open-weather-app.netlify.app), when you search for a city such as *Paris*, neither the map, time, nor the headings update. However, the strange thing is that when I test this on my localhost machine, it works as expected, but it doesn't work on Netlify.

If you have [Redux Devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) installed, you'll notice that my search query is working, but the page doesn't update when pressing the enter key on the keyboard.

Would anyone have any experience as to why my search is not working on my staging site, but works on my localhost?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The page at `https://bn-open-weather-app.netlify.app/` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Calgary&appid=7b8a500a88e8350595f27158da3190df`. **This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.** -- the error is self explanatory. Change `http` in API calls to `https`. You can also remove the protocol, `//api.open...` will also work fine. It works on localhost, because you are accessing your site using `http` there; hence there is no "mixed content".

Answer (score 0):

I learned from user *brc-dd* that I need to serve my fetches from `https` or `//` to make my app work.

Thanks a lot!